# How to add a lightning component dynamically?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript

I want to add a lightning component within a component with providing a dynamic name to the component.
For example :- if I have 2 components then in javascript I will add component 1 other wise add component 2 in the app based on some condition/criteria.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can load a Lightning component dynamically using Javascript.

For example:

```
$A.createComponent(
        "c:YourCustomComponentName", //the name of your custom component
        {
            "yourAttribute1": theValueToPass, //Here are the attributes needed to load your custom component
            "yourAttribute2": theValueToPass2
        },
        function(newComponent, status, errorMessage){ //Your new created component is stored in the newComponent variable  
            //Here you can add the new component body to your current component  
            var targetCmp = component.find('theContainer'); //Here you select the component in which you want to add the new created component
            var body = targetCmp.get("v.body");
            body.push(newComponent);
            targetCmp.set("v.body", body); 
        }
);
```